# Use of ARDL, VECM, along with the Multiple OLS Method

Tags: stationarity, vector-error-correction-model, ardl

Besides ARDL & VECM, in the Multiple OLS, I regress the dependent Y(0) time series with independent time series (19 in number) X(0) and (4 in number) X(1) variables. The residuals are serially uncorrelated at BG Serial correlation tests, the coefficients stable at 5 percent level, the CUSUM Stability Diagnostic test shows stable at 5.2 percent level, R-square value is 0.313, Adj. R-square is 0.206, F-value (p-values) is 2.916 (0.001), DW stat is 2.092. Can I accept the OLS method besides the ARDL and VECM observations?

Comment: The observations in Multiple OLS is to some extent important since it has the long-run relationships.

Comment: What is multiple OLS? While ARDL and VECM are models, OLS is not a model but an estimation technique. Do you perhaps mean multiple regression?

Comment: Actually, besides the ARDL and VECM I have tried to get the long run OLS relationship as it is there. The ARDL and VECM models are fine but with reduced information since none of them use level data. Hence, I have also include the OLS estimated results. Here, the dependent Y is I(0), a few of the X are I(1) while the most are I(0). The residual in the Multiple OLS is I(0). Hence, even if the model is marginally stable in the terms of level of significance i.e. 5.2percent. Will I neglect this long run specifications totally. Making first differences violates the meaning the proxy valuables do.

Comment: Yes, it means multiple OLS regression.

Comment: VECM does not suffer from reduced information. After all, it has an equivalent representation as a restricted VAR model in levels.

Comment: What happens is that both VECM and ARDL models, in the right hand side, there is absence of level data, and they are either the lagged variables and/or differences of the explanatory variables. The theory in the study demands level data while lagged or the difference data means something else. For example, the independent variable is a particular attention level 
viz. aggregate attention, and its differences show selective attention, and lagged data does not fulfill the need of current decision making. The theory demands use of Xs but a few say four X's data series are I(1) others are I(0).

Comment: Then use a restricted VAR representation of the VEC model instead. The model is the same, just the representation is different. (Think about it: you have observations of $y_t$ and a VEC model for $\Delta y_{t+1}$; this yields $y_{t+1}$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do a trial with it.

Comment: Can I use VARX if a few (four Explanatory) Xs are I(1) and the more (nineteen) Xs are I(0)? Please clarify the query?

Comment: Do your estimation in in VECM and then convert back to restricted VAR.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definitely use this approach.

Comment: Sir, I hope what you are suggesting makes a similarity what the author in the link advises, https://help.macrobond.com/analyses/statistical/vector-autoregression/